# C# What is better, read all lines or take substrings from one line?

Tags: c#, io

I have a list of words (around 300) in a text file, with all words of equal length. I created a method that takes two random words from that list:

```cs
private static string InitializeWords(Random rand)
{
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(Constants.Heterograms);
    int number = rand.Next(0, lines.Length - 1);
    return lines[number];
}
```

It works as it should, but I was wondering, if I go about it correctly. This method is called everytime a new instance of an object is created, so I wonder if this hurts performance. For example, would it be better to place each word on one line, and take two random substrings from that line? Or does it not matter too much?

Comment: Assuming the words are all using the Latin alphabet (or are using some form of fixed-size text encoding) you could have them all on one line, and just seek to that exact position in the file.

Comment: " I wonder if this hurts performance." Well don't just _wonder_. Use a profiler and actually _measure_ it.

Comment: That method only returns one random word. If you need two, you shouldn't read the file again.

Comment: "I created a method that takes two random words"...are you sure? The method you've shown only returns one.

Comment: Sorry, I phrased that incorrectly. It does only return one, but it is called twice on two separate text files

Comment: You can get total words count like `var count = new FileInfo(Constants.Heterograms).Length / wordLengthInBytes;`, then use your random like `var index = rand.Next(0, count - 1);` and then just read a single line like this: `var line = File.ReadLines(Constants.Heterograms).Skip(number).First();`